# How to display all the Chapter's name in a document without using minitoc, titletoc, shorttoc, toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

How can I get all the name of my chapter without using a ToC please ?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}


\part{part ONE}

%Display all the chapter name of Part ONE

\chapter{One}
\chapter {Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we get a MWE by you? ;-)

Comment: *How* do you want to "display all the chapter names"? A ToC is the ideal way, or perhaps something like a mini-ToC.

Comment: Minitoc, shorttoc, titletoc are not working with my memoir document :) and I have already a TOC at the beginning of my doc...

Comment: Maybe if you write a code in your preamble where you do the same task that those packages you don't want to use ;-)

Comment: Yes, a kind of script

Comment: In my admittedly limited experience, minitoc works very well with memoir. Maybe you need to ask a different question (with MWE): "Why is minitoc not working with memoir in my document"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use `etoc`? You at least don't mention it and it is designed to respect `memoir`'s configuration. (For example, it ensures that ToCs are added to the ToC if `memoir` is loaded.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \part{part ONE}
  \localtableofcontents

  \chapter{One}
  \chapter {Two}

  \part{part two}
  \localtableofcontents

  \chapter{three}
  \chapter{four}

\end{document}
```

This will produce a main ToC:

[image: main ToC]

a ToC for part 1:

[image: part 1 ToC]

and a ToC for part 2:

[image: part 2 ToC]

## EDIT

Just to respond to your query regarding different configurations for the main and local ToCs, `etoc` allows you to do entirely ridiculous things, even. If you want, you can use a different layout for every ToC in your document, typeset the same ToC in different ways, and print particular elements of your ToC in bright orange italics against a green background with a blue border. This example just shows a couple of different local ToCs using two of `etoc`'s default formats: `ruled` and `framed`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \part{part ONE}
  \etoclocalruled[1]{Local Contents Rules!}

  \chapter{One}
  \chapter {Two}

  \part{part two}
  \etoclocalframed[2]{Local Contents Framed}

  \chapter{three}
  \chapter{four}
  \chapter{five}
  \chapter{six}

  \part{part three}
  \localtableofcontents
  \chapter{seven}
  \chapter{eight}

\end{document}
```

This produces the standard main ToC:

[image: main toc in default style]

a ToC with a rule for part 1:

[image: ruled toc]

a framed ToC for part 2:

[image: framed toc]

and a local ToC in the default style for part 3:

[image: local default toc]

Obviously, it would be crazy to change styles for every ToC. However, you can easily change the global style after issuing the main `\tableofcontents`. (You can also restore the default later if you prefer to put your main ToC later for some reason.) The package manual should give you a sense of the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks cfr, it is working !!! However, is it possible to modify the style of my etoc's table of content without affecting the true toc ?

Comment: @Terriguest That code doesn't modify the style of the main ToC as far as I can tell. At least, if I remove `etoc` and the local ToCs, the style of the main ToC looks the same to me. Could you explain what difference you see?

Comment: There is no difference. But I would like two difference styles for my two toc.

Comment: @Terriguest Oh. Yes. `etoc` certainly lets you do that. You can have a different style for every ToC if you wish to. The documentation has lots of examples.

Comment: @Terriguest See updated question. I have no idea what you want to do so I've just demonstrated that you can configure the format of the ToCs independently.

Comment: Oh my God !!! Thank you so much! It is amazing.  
Edit : to remove the Contents' title line in the toc you have to use    `\etoclocalruled*[1]{Local Contents Rules!}`

Comment: @Terriguest Oh. Yes. That's because you are using `memoir` and `etoc` respects its configuration by default. (Apparently `memoir` puts the title of the ToC in the ToC.)

Comment: +1 but "*bright orange italics against a green background with a blue border*": that was the whole idea of `etoc`, thus I give to your answer only a `9.5/10` because it lacks an illustration `;-)`.

Comment: @jfbu A perfect answer would risk offending the deities of TeX.

Comment: @cfr alas... will there ever be a Nadia Comăneci of the `etoc` ?...

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to reuse the ToC and extract only the contents for every `\part`. This is discussed via example in the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (sniplet **C.7 (USING CLASS TOOLS TO MAKE A CHAPTER TOC)**, p 405). The following discussion is taken from the manual with some modifications (chapter > part) to match your requirement...

---

By using a few hooks, we will be able to create a simple part ToC. First a few notes:

1. In this class, the ToC data can be reused, thus we can load the ToC data as many times
   as we would like.
2. Data in the ToC is stored as arguments to the `\contentsline` macro, say (see also Figure 9.1 on page 143):

   ```
   \contentsline{part}{\partnumberline {I}Test}{3}
   ```

   where the first argument determines which macro is used to process the data. Each of these macros look at the value of the `tocdepth` counter to know whether to typeset or not.
3. Using some hooks we can insert local changes to `tocdepth` in order to only typeset the sections from the current part.

The idea is to be able to add hooks at key points in the ToC data, and then use these
hooks to enable and disable typesetting.

We will need to add hooks just after a part line (like the one above), and we will
need to be able to insert hooks just before items that mark the end of a part, that is the next `\part`, `\book`, plus a macro like `\appendixpage` which also write to the
ToC.

First we define hooks that add hooks into the ToC. We use a counter to make each start
and end hook unique. We add end markers above the ToC entries for `\part` and
`\book`.

```
\newcounter{tocmarker}
\renewcommand\mempreaddparttotochook {\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
\renewcommand\mempreaddbooktotochook {\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
\renewcommand\mempreaddapppagetotochook{\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
% start marker
\renewcommand\mempostaddparttotochook{%
  \stepcounter{tocmarker}\cftinserthook{toc}{start-\thetocmarker}}
\let\normalchangetocdepth\changetocdepth % for later
```

The hooks inserted into the ToC file, does nothing by default. You will notice that the line above will now look like:

```
\cftinsert {end-0}
\contentsline{part}{\partnumberline {I}Test}{3}
\cftinsert {start-1}
...
\cftinsert {end-1}
\contentsline{part}{\partnumberline {II}Test}{5}
```

Thus to get a part ToC command we need to make sure that (1) all entries are disabled,
(2) at `start-1` we re-enable ToC entries, and (3) at `end-1` disable ToC entries again. Here is the rest of the code, explained via comments.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\parttoc{
  % make changes local, remember counters a global
  \begingroup
    % store current value, to be restored later
    \setcounter{@memmarkcntra}{\value{tocdepth}}
    % when ever \settocdepth is used, it adds the new value to the
    % ToC data. This cause problems when we want to disable all
    % entries. Luckily the data is added via a special macro, we
    % redefine it, remember we stored the original value earlier.
    \let\changetocdepth\@gobble
    % disable all entries (using our copy from above)
    \normalchangetocdepth{-10}
    % enable ToC data within our block, we go as far as subsubsection
    \cftinsertcode{start-\thetocmarker}{\normalchangetocdepth{3}}
    % when the block is done, disable the remaining
    \cftinsertcode{end-\thetocmarker}{\normalchangetocdepth{-10}}
    % remove the spacing above the ToC title
    \let\tocheadstart\relax
    % remove the ToC title itself
    \let\printtoctitle\@gobble
    % remove space below title
    \let\aftertoctitle\relax
    % reformat ToC entries:
    \setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\cftsectionindent}{\cftchapternumwidth}
    \setlength{\cftsubsectionindent}{\cftsectionnumwidth}
    \setlength{\cftsubsubsectionindent}{\cftsubsectionindent}
    \addtolength{\cftsubsubsectionindent}{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}
    \renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionfont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionpagefont{\small}
    % include the actual ToC data
    \tableofcontents*
  \endgroup
  % restore tocdepth
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{@memmarkcntra}}
  % to indent or not after the chapter ToC
  \m@mindentafterchapter
  % space between part ToC and text
  \par\bigskip
  % handles indentation after the macro
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

Note that if the `\partprecistoc` or `\partprecis` has been used then that
data is also added to the ToC data, and we will need to locally disable it in the part
ToC. This can be done by adding

```
\let\precistoctext\@gobble
```

to the `\parttoc` definition above, just make sure it is added before calling before
`\tableofcontents*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcounter{tocmarker}
\renewcommand\mempreaddparttotochook {\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
\renewcommand\mempreaddbooktotochook {\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
\renewcommand\mempreaddapppagetotochook{\cftinserthook{toc}{end-\thetocmarker}}
% start marker
\renewcommand\mempostaddparttotochook{%
  \stepcounter{tocmarker}\cftinserthook{toc}{start-\thetocmarker}}
\let\normalchangetocdepth\changetocdepth % for later

\makeatletter
\newcommand\parttoc{
  % make changes local, remember counters a global
  \begingroup
    % store current value, to be restored later
    \setcounter{@memmarkcntra}{\value{tocdepth}}
    % when ever \settocdepth is used, it adds the new value to the
    % ToC data. This cause problems when we want to disable all
    % entries. Luckily the data is added via a special macro, we
    % redefine it, remember we stored the original value earlier.
    \let\changetocdepth\@gobble
    % disable all entries (using our copy from above)
    \normalchangetocdepth{-10}
    % enable ToC data within our block, we go as far as section
    \cftinsertcode{start-\thetocmarker}{\normalchangetocdepth{1}}
    % when the block is done, disable the remaining
    \cftinsertcode{end-\thetocmarker}{\normalchangetocdepth{-10}}
    % remove the spacing above the ToC title
    \let\tocheadstart\relax
    % remove the ToC title itself
    \let\printtoctitle\@gobble
    % remove space below title
    \let\aftertoctitle\relax
    % reformat ToC entries:
    \setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\cftsectionindent}{\cftchapternumwidth}
    \renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\small}
    \renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\small}
    % include the actual ToC data
    \tableofcontents*
  \endgroup
  % restore tocdepth
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{@memmarkcntra}}
  % to indent or not after the chapter ToC
  \m@mindentafterchapter
  % space between part ToC and text
  \par\bigskip
  % handles indentation after the macro
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

\parttoc

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\end{document}
```

Note that you have the `\parttoc` on a separate page from the `\part` title. You have do modify some of the `\part` internals and perhaps some of `\parttoc` to display things on the same page properly. However, for now, without more guidelines, this should suffice.